# Adobe AIR3 Mobile – Is it possible to add native Android visual elements with native extensions?

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, flex4.6, air-native-extension

i need to add some native android elements to stage. Is it real?

Comment: I know this isn't recommended, but i need some native functionality with "editText". StageText with spark components, don't have this. In other words, i need a native android textarea with htmltext.

Comment: I need only native textinput. Flex mobile textarea so slow and laggy.

Answer (score 2):

@Acrossfy,

Adobe Native Extensions allow native Android functionality to be added to your AIR based App. However Adobe Engineers strongly recommend that you do not attempt to write Native Extensions (ANEs) for UI Elements. They recommend that you use the MXML Mobile Spark Components for UI building. You can however add native Android features like Toast Alerts and Vibration.

Adobe's Official ANE list:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html

ANEs we've developed at JamPot:
http://www.jampot.ie/ane/

Comment: I know this isn't recommended, but i need some native functionality with "editText". StageText with spark components, don't have this. In other words, i need a native android textarea with htmltext.

Comment: I need only native textinput. Flex mobile textarea so slow and laggy.

Comment: Just to be sure - are you using Debug mode? If so, you should to do an Export (slow build) to get the best speed. However, speed is a cost of using the AIR runtime. I have previously used AIR to publish iOS IPAs, Android APKs, and BlackBerry BARs, but now (with the exception of BlackBerry) I would recommend creating new Apps with native tools (Xcode/Eclipse) unless the Application was already written in Flash/Flex/AS3. However it must be said AIR works best on BlackBerry 10 (QNX), as they worked very closely with Adobe and thats why I think its fast on that platform only.